# Desktop settings no longer being applied

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon

So my Mint setup (Mint 17 on a Lenovo Yoga 13) was working perfectly fine earlier this morning. However, I pressed Ctrl+Alt+PgDn while trying to change between workspaces and it turned the entire screen into a terminal window (similar to the one seen when hitting Alt+F2 at the login screen). I logged in using my information, realized I just needed to reboot, and then did so. However, when I logged back in, my entire desktop was reset to default settings and I couldn't change any of my desktop settings at all. It turns out my home folder's permissions had been changed from my account to root, so I changed them back to how they originally were and rebooted. The issue still persisted however, so I honestly have no idea what to do at this point. Now every time I log in my desktop resets itself as if Mint was just installed. My applications work fine however. I may be missing something really obvious so if anyone has any thoughts it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your home directory permissions recursively?

i.e. (replace 'user1' with your user name)

```
chown -R user1:user1 /home/user1/
```

Note: If you did not already know, always be extremely careful when running chown recursively, as it can be very tricky to undo if you change permissions for everything in a directory with a variety of file/directory ownerships set for various files and directories within it.

Comment: I tried this and rebooted, and it still reset my desktop as if it were a fresh installation.

Comment: If your situation persists, I will need more information to help you out.

Did you run the recursive chown as root? Also, are your configuration files still present and now having the correct permissions?